# QStyleSheetStyleCaches::objectDestroyed crashes

Tags: c++, windows, qt, crash

This is the Qt code in qstylesheetstyle.cpp

```
void QStyleSheetStyleCaches::objectDestroyed(QObject *o)
{
    styleRulesCache.remove(o);
    hasStyleRuleCache.remove(o);
    renderRulesCache.remove(o);
    customPaletteWidgets.remove((const QWidget *)o);
    customFontWidgets.remove(static_cast<QWidget *>(o));
    styleSheetCache.remove(o);
    autoFillDisabledWidgets.remove((const QWidget *)o);
}
```

When object `o` destroyed, Qt invokes that function to clean QStyleSheet. But sometimes it crashes in  `customPaletteWidgets.remove((const QWidget *)o);` line.
I suspect that because object has already gone so that const cast `const QWidget *)o` return invalid pointer, or something wrong with this `customPaletteWidgets` QHash when insert and remove items. I am using windows 7.

Does anyone has any idea?